# What is the difference between these noun phrases?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Live performance by Zedd in Amsterdam.

Live performance by Zedd to Amsterdam.

What is the difference between both

Comment: "**to**" isn't idiomatic in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Live performance by Zedd **in** Amsterdam.

'in' is describing **where** it happened

---

Live performance by Zedd **to** Amsterdam.

'to' is describing **who**/**what** (indirect object) that received the performance

Comment: This is true, but it's hard for this US English speaker to imagine a context in which the second one might actually be used, unless it were split across multiple phrases, like "We are broadcasting / the live performance by Zedd / to Amsterdam."